# Angular http request to an apiend point must complete before other requests can execute

Tags: angular, http

I have a service

```
export class FreteService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router) { }

    recuperarFrete(dados_entrega: DadosEntrega): any{

      return this.http.post<DadosEntrega>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + 'entrega/calcular-frete', dados_entrega, {observe: 'response'});

    }

}
```

And it is called on a component ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.freteService.recuperarFrete(dados_entrega)


}
```

If I navigate to another component the http requests on the other component will be pending until this request completes. I notice it because the endpoint takes about 50 seconds to return a result. Wasn't http requests supposed to be asynchronous?

Comment: How fast the client receives a result from the server has nothing to do with the call being asynchronous. Asynchronous just means that the application does not block on the response. Also I do not see how the call is even occurring as you never subscribe to the returned Observable which means the call won't happen.

Comment: @Igor. If I have "request one" taking 50s and "request two" taking 2s, I was expecting to see the results of "request two" first, even though it executed last. In my code it is waiting for the "request one" to complete.

Comment: **Or** this call taxeses the server or causes a lock or blocks in the database etc. By default there is no client side blocking for http calls in angular. If you want more help you need to include an [mcve].

Comment: Yes, now I see, it seems that the problem is on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the first request should be canceled by the browser when component is destroyed. I suspect there is a problem with the code presented, it's missing call to unsubscribe in OnDestroy. You will probably have to add ngOnDestroy and call unsubscribe from there. This should cancel a request that is in progress when component is destroyed.

```js
class MyComponent implements onDestroy {
  private subscription: Subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.freteService.recuperarFrete(dados_entrega);
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```